# Adding constraint in PostgreSQL that requires information from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, check-constraints

I have the following schema in PostgreSQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE exam (
    exam_id INT,
    exam_name TEXT,
    total_marks INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(exam_id)
);

CREATE TABLE studentmarks (
    studentmarks_id INT,
    student_id INT,
    exam_id INT,
    marks_scored INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(studentmarks_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(exam_id) REFERENCES exam ON DELETE SET NULL,
);
```

How can I enforce the constraint that `studentmarks.marks_scored <= exam.total_marks` such that the behaviour is just like the `CHECK` constraint?

Comment: @SalmanA it should be correct now

Comment: What  action do you want when a query sets `exam.total_marks`  below an existing `studentmarks.marks_scored` ?

Comment: @Serg that should behave just like a `CHECK (...)` constraint in PostgreSQL

Comment: Looks like a case for two triggers, on both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `trigger`.

You need to create `trigger` function first.

```
-- FUNCTION: public.check_marks_calculation()

-- DROP FUNCTION public.check_marks_calculation();

CREATE FUNCTION public.check_marks_calculation()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
_exam_id integer;
_total_marks integer;
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
_exam_id = NEW.exam_id;
_total_marks = (select total_marks from exam where exam_id=_exam_id);
if(NEW.marks_scored <= _total_marks) then
RETURN NEW;
else
raise exception 'Student Marks greater than exam Total Marks.';
end if;
end if;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.check_marks_calculation()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Then create `trigger`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_toal_marks
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON public.studentmarks 
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.check_marks_calculation();
```

**NOTE** I have tested in `postgres`